# Laravel getting ids of a collection without foreach

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My code currently looks like this:

```
foreach ($things as $thing) {
            $ids[] = $thing->id;
        }
dd(Other::whereIn('thing_id', $ids)->get());
```

Thing model has many Other

```
    public function others()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Other::class);
    }
```

It's working, but can I achieve this functionality without using the foreach? It doesn't seems to be clean for me. I've tried to give whole collection to where in like this:

```
dd(Other::whereIn('thing_id', $things)->get());
```

but this only returned where id was 1.

I'm looking for help to clean up this code, any help appreciated.

Comment: $things->pluck('id')

Comment: User `pluck` of Eloquent Collection. `get()` & `all()` returns Eloquent Collention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function called "pluck"

You can apply it on a collection as following

```php
$collection->pluck('id');
```

More can be seen on docs

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 0):

I've already found a way to clean it up a bit, instead of foreach I can simply use :

```
$ids=$things->pluck('id');
```

If there's a cleaner way pls show me :)